# (In stable diffusion) Why are the vae encoded latents sampled by adding randomness to their mean, instead of just taking the mean directly?

Tags: python, image-processing

In the diffuser's code base they calculate the input `img2img` latents in the following manner:

```
init_latents = self.vae.encode(image).latent_dist.sample()
noise = randn_tensor(shape)
init_latents = self.scheduler.add_noise(init_latents, noise, timestep)
```

With the implementation of latent_dist.sample being:

```
self.mean + self.std * randn_tensor(self.mean.shape)
```

I am correct in thinking there is no reason to add noise twice, or am I missing some fundamental reason for this strange behavior?

Answer (score 0):

The first line seems to be adding a 1$\sigma$ standard deviation to the latent vector as a whole. In the third line it seems there is random noise being added to the individual components of the latent space vector?

I'm guessing this could be to make sure input latent as a whole will take on the overall shape or 'structure' of the input image in latent space, but shifted around by 1$\sigma$ (to ensure it's not the same image). Then the random noise is added on top of it to aid in the diffusion process?